# Error message System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, xna

i am writing some menu code thats causes fade in/outs when going between the menus and i have ran into a small snag i usually make the easiest of mistakes to fix but never seem to spot whats under my own nose if anyone could have a look and tell me how stupid i am would be greatful.

```
public override float Alpha
{
    get
    {
        return Alpha;
    }
    set
    {
        Alpha = value;

        if (alpha == 1.0f)
        {
            increase = false;
        }
        else if (alpha == 0.0f)
        {
            increase = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

thats the code and the full error message is - An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Platformer.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your capitalization. You meant to write:

```
public override float Alpha 
{
   get
   {
      return alpha;
   }
   set
   {
      alpha = value;

      // more code...
   }
}
```

The way you wrote it, Alpha is calling itself first. Which will call itself first. Which will... you get the pattern :)

Comment: thank you its not even funny how many times Case sensitivity messes with my coding

Answer (score 0):

if alpha is name of private field then in get write

```
get 
{
return alpha;
}
```

and in setter first set private field as:

```
set
{
alpha=value;
}
```

and after this write other code.